# SQL Server: select on a table that contains a blob

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob

My app is querying - among the rest - a table that has a blob column and other metadata columns (no other LOB columns).

I've read that if the object itself is not too big, it may still be stored inside the table and not as a link to itself. In this case, a 'SELECT' statement on such a table, even if it does not contain the blob, like:

```
SELECT Date FROM MyTable
```

might still retrieve the blob (in the server only), thus taking longer to perform.

Is this true? Can anyone provide an explanation or a link to one?

My background in SQL is rather basic, so I might not be accurate, sorry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a non-clustered index on the date column, then you can retrieve the data by scanning the index, instead of scanning the entire table. You should see I/O go way down.

Comment: The date was an example. I retrieve several columns of information, not just one, and the date is changing (it's 'last updated'), I'm not sure if it's good for indexing.
Anyway, I have a clustered index on the Id column. Thing is, I think that if the blob is a part of the index, it means slower search, am I right?

Comment: @Noich There is no yes or no answer for that, sorry. A LOB column can't be part of a non-clustered index, unless you mean INCLUDE.