# Why Select SQL queries on tables with blobs are slow, even when the blob is not selected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, blob

SELECT queries on tables with BLOBs are slow, even if I don't include the BLOB column. Can someone explain why, and maybe how to circumvent it? I am using SQL Server 2012, but maybe this is more of a conceptual problem that would be common for other distributions as well.

I found this post: [SQL Server: select on a table that contains a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671226/sql-server-select-on-a-table-that-contains-a-blob), which shows the same problem, but the marked answer doesn't explain why is this happening, neither provides a good suggestion on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you too using SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 R2, but I guess this will be common for many MS SQL Server versions, as well as maybe other SQL servers?

Comment: it could be because - maybe SQL cannot cache the table pages as easily, and you have to go to the disk more often.  I'm no expert as to why though - if it is happening, then try the table redesign I mentioned, if you ever do need the blob, just do a join

Comment: @AndrewDeighton, you mean SQL Server here, not SQL...

Comment: yes SQL Server sorry - you might want to look at FILESTREAM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking for a way to solve the performance drag, there are a number of approaches that you can take.  Adding indexes to your table should help massively provided you aren't simply selecting the entire recordset.  Creating views over the table may also assist.  It's also worth checking the levels of index fragmentation on the table as this can cause poor performance and could be addressed with a regular maintenance job.  The suggestion of creating a linked table to store the blob data is also a genuinely good one.

However, if your question is asking why it's happening, this is because of the fundamentals of the way MS SQL Server functions.  Essentially your database, and all databases on the server and split into pages, 8kb chunks of data with a 96-byte header.  Each page representing what is possible in a single I/O operation.  Pages are collected contained and grouped within Exents, 64kb collections of eight contiguous pages.  SQL Server therefore uses sixteen Exents per megabyte of data.  There are a few differing page types, a data page type for example won't contain what are termed "Large Objects".  This include the data types text, image, varbinary(max), xml data, etc...  These also are used to store variable length columns which exceed 8kb (and don't forget the 96 byte header).

At the end of each page will be a small amount of free space.  Database operations obviously shift these pages around all the time and free space allocations can grow massively in a database dealing with large amounts of I/O and random record access / modification.  This is why free space on a database can grow massively.  There are tools available within the management suite to allow you to reduce or remove free space and basically this re-organizes pages and exents.

Now, I may be making a leap here but I'm guessing that the blobs you have in your table exceed 8kb.  Bear in mind if they exceed 64kb they will not only span multiple pages but indeed span multiple exents.  The net result of this will be that a "normal" table read will cause massive amounts of I/O requests.  Even if you're not interested in the BLOB data, the server may have to read through the pages and exents to get the other table data.  This will only be compounded as more transactions make pages and exents that make up a table to become non-contiguous.

Where "Large Objects" are used, SQL Server writes Row-Overflow values which include a 24bit pointer to where the data is actually stored.  If you have several columns on your table which exceed the 8kb page size combined with blobs and impacted by random transactions, you will find that the majority of the work your server is doing is I/O operations to move pages in and out of memory, reading pointers, fetching associated row data, etc, etc...  All of which represents serious overhead.

Comment: Good. So you are saying that where "large objects" are used, SQL server writes some pointers to another place where the large object is actually stored (you guessed right, my objects are between 50 kB and 3MB). So why is the engine loading whatever is in the location where the BLOB reference points to? If I make a query which does not include the BLOB, why go fetch it? Or maybe if those Exents, where the BLOB is placed, contained more data? Then why fetch all of it and not only the first and last one, provided that they are sequential and my BLOB spans over say 10 of them.

Comment: You've answered your own question there; there is no guarantee they are sequentially (or even contiguously) stored.  Don't assume that a 50kb object resides in 7 pages which is therefore one exent.  There is every chance that the 7 pages which make up that object exist in two, three or even seven different exents.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for clearing this up. Maybe add it to your answer so that it is completely clear to anyone who might encounter the same :)

Comment: Upvoted, btw it should be exTents, instead of exents.

Answer (score 2):

I got a suggestion then, have all the blobs in a separate table with an identity ID, then only save the identity ID in your main table

it could be because - maybe SQL cannot cache the table pages as easily, and you have to go to the disk more often. I'm no expert as to why though.

A lot of people frown at BLOBS/images in databases - In SQL 2012 there is some sort of compromise where you can configure the DB to keep objects in a file structure, not in the actual DB anymore - you might want to look for that

Comment: I guess this is the best way to go, only that this doesn't answer the question for what is the reason about this. Also, there is currently no possible way my company started doing this change, so I am looking for a different approach.